# WebElement (Selenium/Python)

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to upload a image to https://www.alibaba.com/ through Selenium.

So i find the element which allows me to do that:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\migue\Desktop\WorkerBot\Drivers\chromedriver')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.alibaba.com/');
time.sleep(5)

#Open menu to upload image
wait =  WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
x = True
while x:
    x = False
    try:
        search_camara = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'i.ui-searchbar-imgsearch-icon'))) 
        search_camara.click()
    except:
        x = True
        driver.refresh()
time.sleep(5)

searcher1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="J_SC_header"]/header/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div/div')
print(searcher1.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```

When i print out searcher1  i get:

```
<div class="upload-btn-wrapper"><div class="upload-btn" style="z-index: 1;">Upload Image</div><div id="html5_1cu85jlnu116m14sle1omtch5s3_container" class="moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5" style="position: absolute; top: 14px; left: 183px; width: 109px; height: 28px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;"><input id="html5_1cu85jlnu116m14sle1omtch5s3" type="file" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" multiple="" accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/bmp"></div>
```

Max 2MB per Image

That's the element i need to upload the image, but when i try to do the following:

**Option 1**

```
searcher1.find_element_by_class_name('.moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5')
```

**Option 2**

```
searcher1.find_element_by_class_name('upload-btn')
```

**Option 3**

```
searcher1.find_element_by_xpath('/div')
```

I get the following (for option 3, for example):

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/div"}
```

What's the problem? I'm stuck :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For relative xpath, you need to put a `.` in front of it. Try:

```
searcher1.find_element_by_xpath('./div')
```

Comment: Thanks. After that if: searcher2 = searcher1.find_element_by_xpath('./div')- Could i use searcher2.send_keys(path) to upload the image i want, right?

Comment: I don't think so. You'd need to send_keys to the `input` element of type `file`